# Fourier on discrete but not sequential data

Tags: fourier-analysis, interpolation

I have time series data, which is discrete as it is timestamped with microsecond resolution. It is not *sequential*, as in not every microsecond has a value. How would I go about Fourier in such a case? I figured I could just interpolate the missing data points, but this ended up with my machine running out of memory as the individual data points have quite some distance between them. I could also reduce the resolution, but before I do that I wanted to ask whether there is a better way than interpolation in the first place.

Comment: Are you interested in an actual Fourier transform (reversible, useful for filtering) or in an estimate of the power spectral density (not reversible, useful for statistics)? For the latter, "Numerical recipes [in C]" by Press, Teukolsky, Vetterling and Flannery (1992), 2nd edition, has algorithms for unevenly sampled data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are libraries for nonequispaced fast Fourier transform or nonuniform fast Fourier transform. [NFFT](http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~potts/nfft/download.php) interpolates irregular data onto a regular grid followed by a standard FFT algorithm. If your data has some large gaps then I would try to break the data into chunks, and/or indeed reduce the resolution or decimate to study the low frequency spectra.